# chrome adding quotes to html

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have a very weird problem, I have a markup, which is being treated by chrome (tested on mac, windows, and ubuntu-chromium) in weird manner..

I've created a simple version of the situation..

```
<h3>First Part<span>Content in Span</span></h3>​
```

Chrome is adding extra quotes to `First Part`, while its not present in any other browser (tested on Firefox, and ie.)

Simple demo I've created on [JsFiddle here..](http://jsfiddle.net/wr4BV/1/)

In Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

In Firefox:
[image]

Comment: Chrome wraps text nodes in quotes if there is another element present. If you remove the `span`, the quotes should go away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just the way that chrome presents the text node content in the element inspector. You can see white-space better this way. The quotes are purely virtual.

Comment: Oh no, my output looked funny for some other reason, but I just spent half an hour trying to get rid of the quotes appearing in the element inspection. It might be more intuitive if something besides quotes were used, such as ⌜and ⌟.

Answer (score 5):

The quotes do not exist in your HTML document. They just appear in Chrome, to show that you are viewing the text content of an element.

You shouldn't worry about them at all. If you check the Source code (right click, View Page Source), you will see that they are not there.